# Where can i find scriptural references for vaahan puja?

Tags: temple, puja, vahana

It is a custom to take the newly purchased car to a nearby temple, where the pujari consecrates it. It typically involves tying a lemon somewhere on the hood, breaking a coconut in front of car etc. Quite often a murti of Ganeshji is kept on the dashboard.

I was wondering if there are any scriptural basis for it ? Any stories associated with vahan puja?

Comment: Also vahana puja on Dusshera.